# Horizontal Navbar with images; CSS not displaying "inline"

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css. I'm attempting to have my navbar display horizontally and have background images above the text links.

Here's is my failed/attempted code:

CSS:

```css
#aside_sect_mm {
 margin: 0px;
 background-position: 0%;
 background-color: #004E27;
 max-width: 704px;
 max-height: 100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: relative;
}

#aside_sect_mm nav {
 text-align: justify;
 max-width: 704px;
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 100px;
 margin-top: 0%;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 704px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-align: justify;
 list-style: none;
 line-height: 3.5em;
 position: relative;
 padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin-left: 4.5em;
 max-height: 100px; 
 color: #FCE011;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon  {
 position: relative;
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 0%;
 display: block;
}


#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
 background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
 background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
 background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
 background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
 background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 50%;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #F6EF1B;
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover, #aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover  {
    position: relative;
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 50%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F6EF1B;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: -26px 0%;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #004E27;
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover {
 background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover {
 background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover {
 background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover {
 background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
 background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}

And the HTML:
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
</head>

<body>
<section id="aside_sect_mm">
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
<li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a></li>
<li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a></li>
<li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
<li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
</ul>
</nav>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

If someone's expertise can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: where is the background image ?

Answer (score 0):

There is really a lot to change here, but I'd start with researching "horizontal alignment".  In this case, you'll want to set those elements (nav ul li) display to 'inline-block'.  In regards to the background image, you were missing the quotes ("../svg/...") and I believe you want the image on the 'li', not the 'a'.  I created a jsfiddle for you to try some new things, with a start to what you're looking for:  http://jsfiddle.net/keddkyz5/1/.  The key css changes were:

```
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon 
{
background-image: url("http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg");
width: 100px;
}

#aside_sect_mm nav ul li
{
 display: inline-block !important;   
}
```

I had to add the !important to force the css... you will probably want to avoid that and simply drill down to the specifics on css specificity (cool article here:  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: another article from a great site for CSS tips and tricks:  https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/